# <a> element fills the whole line when removing ALIGN-ITEMS: CENTER

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am learning CSS and I am trying to understand this behavior.

```css
section{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.banner-area a.banner-btn{
  padding: 15px 35px;
  background: crimson; 
}

.banner-area {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner-area">
  <div class="banner-img"></div>
  <h1>Flexbox Website</h1>
  <h3>Responsive Web Design</h3>
  <a href="#" class="banner-btn">Contact us</a> 
</section>
```

I was trying to play with the CSS and I found out that when I removed `align-items: center`, the  element now takes the entire line, but I couldn't understand why.

Can someone help me understand the reason? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the default value for `align-items` is `stretch`. When you remove the `align-items: center` it reverts to the default value, which is `stretch`. By default, it stretches the items vertically, but because you have specified your `flex-direction: column` everything rotates 90 degrees and items stretch horizontally (taking the whole line) instead of vertically (taking the whole column)

Answer (score 2):

The default value of `align-items` is `stretch`, which will stretch the children to fill the flex container.

I found the [CSS Tricks Flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to be really helpful while learning flex